# Accidentally splashed surgical alcohol on a plaster wall

Tags: walls, cleaning, stain

So I was using surgical alcohol in my bathroom when I splashed some of it on the wall. Now I have a pale blue alcohol stain on it. The wall is a plaster wall covered with white paint.

Any ideas on how to remove that stain?

Comment: "*I splashed some of it on the wall.*"  That will happen when you try to take out your own appendix.

Answer (score 3):

Alcohol acts like a paint remover. So rather than thinking of this as a stain on the surface that can be washed away you have to realize that the paint finish has been partially degraded.

This means you will have to repaint a small area of the wall. Often you will find that touching up does not blend very well so you may need to repaint the affected wall from corner to corner to get a good result

Comment: It is, however, worth a shot to repaint the impacted area first to see if you can get a reasonable match. Just do the touch-up knowing that a full repaint may well be in your future.

Comment: Since it's a bathroom, I'd assume the wall is pretty small, so I'd recommend just painting the whole thing from the get go -- it won't take much longer or much more paint, and you won't risk having to do it again after it dries and you find it's not quite as close as you want.  For big walls, especially in spots you don't spend a lot of time looking at, I agree with Freeman's suggestion.

Comment: @NateS.  Did you read the answer I wrote?  “Often you will find that touching up does not blend very well so you may need to repaint the affected wall from corner to corner to get a good result.” Trying to touch it up will perhaps work. If not the spot will cover better when a full wall re coat  is done.   A small wall in a bathroom can have a great desk of cut in work so it’s worth a shot to try touching up first.

Answer (score 1):

Use a primer over the stained area first. Then paint.